# How do I monitor whether a docker container is running with Grafana?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, influxdb

I have the following setup:

- Grafana
- InfluxDB with Telegraf
- Prometheus with cAdvisor

All of these are running in a docker stack.

Since I have some more docker containers running game servers etc., I would like to have a dashboard showing which of my servers are up and which of them are down.

I have tried many Google links, Youtube videos etc. but they all show how to create dashboards of aggregated data like CPU consumption per node etc. which I know how to set up.

Really the only thing I need is a panel showing UP or DOWN for different containers and I have not been able to find anything like that.

**Solution**

Figured it out (in case anyone runs into the same issue):

1. Create a new Stat panel
2. Select Prometheus and write the following query:
   `time() - container_last_seen{name="CONTAINER_NAME"}`
3. Set the format to "Table", I had two Panels otherwise
4. Create ranged value mappings with <60 -> Up and >60 -> Down

There are most likely better solutions but this is what I came up with after some more research.

Comment: Please consider posting your **Solution** as the Answer if it addresses the question. You're permitted to answer your own questions and it has the benefit of marking this question as answered.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks. Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

Figured it out (in case anyone runs into the same issue):

1. Create a new Stat panel
2. Select Prometheus and write the following query:
   `time() - container_last_seen{name="CONTAINER_NAME"}`
3. Set the format to "Table", I had two Panels otherwise
4. Create ranged value mappings with <60 -> Up and >60 -> Down

There are most likely better solutions but this is what I came up with after some more research.

Comment: I used your solution. But why 60?

Answer (score 0):

- I used the following query: `time() - container_last_seen{name="CONTAINER_NAME"}`
- With the condition: `WHEN last() of A IS ABOVE 30`
- With range time :
  `FROM : now-1min TO :now`

A short time range, to avoid errors in case of updated containers...
it works well

[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xew7C.png)

Comment: Note : "IS ABOVE 30" -> 30 is the number of seconds since the container was last seen